# ActionFilter response type (text/html) does not match the response content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

Using: C#, MVC 5, IIS 8

I am trying to implement an ActionFilter that will minify html. The basic approach here is to substitute the response's Stream with a custom Stream that writes input into a MemoryStream and then on the Close method minifies the content stored in the MemoryStream and writes out the (minified) content.

The problem I am having is that although the response's type is 'text/html', the content passed to the custom Stream does *not* look like text or html, it looks like binary. I should add that my site's pages are rendering just fine, so whatever that content is, it's not complete garbage. I added some logging statements to debug, and this is what they look like:

> Minification Error | Chunks: 1 | Url: /Login/iFrameLogin.aspx |
>   Encoding: System.Text.UTF8Encoding | MediaType: text/html | Content:
>   �

I have also tried turning off dynamic compression on my site, and that made no change either. **Does anyone have any ideas why my 'text/html' looks like binary?**

FilterAttribute

```
public class MinifyHtmlFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContextBase context = filterContext.HttpContext;
        HttpRequestBase request = context.Request;
        HttpResponseBase response = context.Response;
        Encoding encoding = response.ContentEncoding;
        string mediaType = response.ContentType;
        string currentUrl = request.RawUrl;
        var minificationManager = HtmlMinificationManager.Current;

        if (response.Filter != null
            && response.StatusCode == 200
            && minificationManager.IsSupportedMediaType(mediaType) //text/html
            && minificationManager.IsProcessablePage(currentUrl))
        {
            response.Filter = new HtmlMinificationFilterStream(response, minificationManager, currentUrl, encoding, mediaType);
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Stream

```
public class HtmlMinificationFilterStream : Stream
{
    private readonly HttpResponseBase _response;
    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly MemoryStream _cacheStream = new MemoryStream();

    private readonly IMarkupMinificationManager _minificationManager;

    private readonly string _currentUrl;
    private readonly Encoding _encoding;
    private readonly string _mediaType;
    private int _chunkCount = 0;

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public HtmlMinificationFilterStream(HttpResponseBase response,
        IMarkupMinificationManager minificationManager,
        string currentUrl,
        Encoding encoding,
        string mediaType)
    {
        _response = response;
        _stream = response.Filter;
        _minificationManager = minificationManager;
        _currentUrl = currentUrl;
        _encoding = encoding;
        _mediaType = mediaType;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return _stream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        _stream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _cacheStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        _chunkCount++;
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _stream.Flush();
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        byte[] cacheBytes = _cacheStream.ToArray();
        int cacheSize = cacheBytes.Length;
        string content = _encoding.GetString(cacheBytes);
        var log = $" | Chunks: {_chunkCount} | Url: {_currentUrl} | Encoding: {_encoding} | MediaType: {_mediaType} | Content: {content}";

        IMarkupMinifier minifier = _minificationManager.CreateMinifier();
        MarkupMinificationResult minificationResult = minifier.Minify(content, _currentUrl, _encoding, false);
        bool isMinified = false;
        if (minificationResult.Errors.Count == 0)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.LogException("MINIFICATION SUCCESS" + log, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_stream, _encoding))
            {
                writer.Write(minificationResult.MinifiedContent);
            }

            isMinified = true;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var error in minificationResult.Errors)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.LogException("Minification Error" + log + " | " + error.SourceFragment, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            }
        }

        if (!isMinified)
        {
            _cacheStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            _cacheStream.CopyTo(_stream);
        }

        _cacheStream.SetLength(0);
        _stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code is really the last thing being executed?  Maybe the binary stream is an internal format, and there is another process afterwards that would normally invisibly convert it back into something for output?

Comment: Finally figured it out (sort of) - it's the IIS compression settings. When I turn off compression on IIS, my stream looks how I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off compression on IIS (8) fixes the issue.